# Java: Keeping leading zeros while reading and formatting a text file

Tags: java, arraylist, io, bufferedreader, filereader

I am having trouble figuring out how to read in a file, line by line, and then format it. The big issue is that I have a text file with a "number" assigned to a "person". The first number is "001". When I try to read it, it only saves as "1". It does the same thing with all leading zeros in my numbers. "002" becomes "2", "030" becomes "30", and so on. Each number has three digits and I want to keep it that way.

Here is the bit of code where I read from the file:

```
do {
    next = Breader.readLine();
    sNumber = Integer.parseInt(next);
    nameArray.add(sNumber);
    sName = Breader.readLine();
    nameArray.add(sName);
    end = Breader.ready();
} while(end);
```

It must be something in the `Integer.parseInt();` function.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class FinalProgram {
    public static void main(String[] args)  IOException {
        nameReader();
    }

    private static void nameReader() throws IOException {
        String nameFile = " ";
        String next = " ";
        int sNumber = 0;
        String sName = " ";
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList nameArray = new ArrayList();

        try {
            System.out.print("Enter the Name file(c:filename.txt): ");
            nameFile = input.nextLine();
        } catch(IllegalArgumentException e) {
            System.out.printf("Invalid input. Please enter"
                    + " filename in the form of "
                    + "c:filename.txt\n", e.getMessage());
        }

        //Instantiate FileReader and BufferedReader
        FileReader freader = new FileReader(nameFile);
        BufferedReader Breader = new BufferedReader(freader);
        boolean end = Breader.ready();

        do {
            next = Breader.readLine();
            sNumber = Integer.parseInt(next);
            nameArray.add(sNumber);
            sName = Breader.readLine();
            nameArray.add(sName);
            end = Breader.ready();
        } while(end);

        System.out.print(nameArray);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you parse a string to an integer like in `int sNumber = Integer.parseInt(next);`, leading zeros will be ignored, since an integer does not have leading zeros, it is superfluous. Why should it store the zeros, would you write `030` instead of `30` on a piece of paper, too? How many zeros should be stored, one, two, ten? How would you compare `0030`, `030` and `30`, are they the same?

As you can see, what you mean is how to **format** as string, an integer is never stored with leading zeros. You can do so, by using `String.format(...);`:

```
int yourInteger = 30;
String formattedNumber = String.format("%03d", yourInteger);

// Prints 30 as 030
System.out.println(formattedNumber);
```

The format string `"%03d"` means: Print an integer, print at least three digits and if there are less than three digits, pad them with leading zeros. Consequently, `30` is printed as `030`, `5` as `005` and `3000` as `3000`, since there are more than three digits.

Another more advanced method to format numbers in general, is [`NumberFormat`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html).

Comment: I like this, but how can I read from the file and have it be an integer? If I try to use Integer.parseInt(n);, it gives me an error.

next = Breader.readLine();
            sNumber = Integer.parseInt(next);
            nameArray.add(sNumber);

Comment: I have tried this: 
next = Breader.readLine();
            sNumber = Integer.parseInt(nf.format(Breader.readLine()));

But it gives me the error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot format given Object as a Number

Comment: Scratch that! I just didn't understand what you meant. Before I stored it in my arraylist, I used String.format, and it works well. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

> Each number has three digits and I want to keep it that way.

Then you need to read it into a String variable.

Or if you need to convert it to an int value for processing, then when you display the value you first need to use a `NumberFormat` to format the output String.

For example:

```
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getIntegerInstance();
nf.setMinimumIntegerDigits(3);
int value = 1;
System.out.println( nf.format(value) );
```

Comment: Great help! Thank you.

Comment: @JonathanDewein, glad it helped. Don't forget to "accept" the answer by clicking on the checkmark so people know the problem has been solved.